# Hamilton's Rules for Quaternions contradict themselves

Tags: quaternions

I recently discovered quaternions and quickly stumbled across a to me contradictory statement. This contradiction already seems to lie in the definition (Hamilton's Rules):
$$i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$$

My issue is with the statement $ijk=-1$
If I just multiply the three squares I get something as follows:
$$i^2j^2k^2=-1$$
$$(ijk)^2=-1$$

Now if I try the same thing from the second equation $ijk=-1$ I get a somewhat contradictory statement:
$$ijk=-1$$
$$(ijk)^2=1$$

All of the operations should be legal as far as I'm concerned but this makes little sense to me. Any explanation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you get $(ijk)^2=-1$?

Comment: from $i^2j^2k^2=-1$

Comment: Multiplication is not commutative so $(ijk)^2$ is not equal to $i^2j^2k^2$

Comment: what's commutative about multiplying those equations?

Comment: How is $(ijk)^2=-1$ meant to follow from $i^2j^2k^2=-1$?

Comment: yes. Is that not legal?

Comment: $(ijk)^2=ijkijk$

Comment: @J.Lengel $(ijk)^2=ijkijk$. I don't see you equating the RHS to $i^2j^2k^2$ any time soon.

Comment: That's a great point I hadn't considered it. Thanks

Comment: @Gae.S. Post your comment as an answer, noting that the multiplication is noncommutative.

Comment: @EthanBolker Anyone may, as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright. That was very simple. I was not following legal algebraic operations.
$$(ijk)^2=-1$$
does not follow from
$$i^2j^2k^2=-1$$
because $(ijk)^2 = ijkijk \ne i^2j^2k^2$